# VBA Excel - How to Access Control within Frame within Worksheet? Refactor / Optimize

Tags: vba, excel, activex

Using Excel 2010

I have a worksheet which contains three ActiveX frames. Each of these frames contains two or more OptionButtons. A reset button on the worksheet resets the values of the optionbuttons to 'False'.

Now, I can reset them all using a separate For loop for each frame:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonReset_Click()

'This button resets all the OptionButtons to False (unchecked)
Dim x As Control

For Each x In Frame1.Controls
        x.Value = False
Next

For Each x In Frame2.Controls
        x.Value = False
Next

For Each x In Frame3.Controls
        x.Value = False
Next

End Sub
```

...but I'd like to reset them all using one nested For loop, like this:

```
Dim xControl as control
Dim xFrame as Frame
```

For Each xFrame in (ActiveSheet.Frames? .Shapes? .OLEObjects?)
    For Each xControl in xFrame
        xControl.Value = False
    Next
Next

After extensive searching online and through books, I can't find the correct way to access each ActiveX frame in the active worksheet.

Comment: Record a macro that selects one of the frames and changes something, and then look at the macro source. If it can be done in code, you'll see how to select a frame in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim o As OLEObject, c

    For Each o In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        'is this a Frame?
        If TypeName(o.Object) = "Frame" Then
            For Each c In o.Object.Controls
                'is this a checkbox?
                If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then
                    c.Value = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next o
End Sub
```